# Does ODS update really improve notes application

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

We use notes 9.0.1 and 8.5.3. In our database properties I see that we have ODS version 41.. Does this need to be upgraded? I read some articles that this IMPROVES performance of the database.

Can anyone please tell if this statement is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is true. Go ahead and upgrade to the latest ODS.

From the [IBM documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/inst_dominoondiskstructure_t.html) on the 9.0.1 release:

> "In this release, Domino supports file format, on-disk structure (ODS)
>   51."
>
> "The current level of ODS provides potential improvement for I/O,
>   folder optimization, compression, and attachment consolidation."

Comment: Thanks Per. Our data subsides on different servers on the network could this cause any problems?

Comment: No, Domino handles this for you: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21102152

Answer (score 1):

ODS 41 is the Notes 5 on-disk storage format. Notes 5 was released 18 years ago, in 1999. IBM engineers have had all that time to come up with ways of optimizing the format in order to improve the efficiency of the storage and retrieval algorithms. Furthermore, there have been major improvements in the typical configurations and capabilities of server hardware - with much more memory and faster CPUs available - allowing IBM's engineers to design algorithms that take advantage of resources that were never available in the 1990s and optimize the ODS for those algorithms.

The performance of most applications in most Notes/Domino environments is i/o-bound, so *of course* using the latest ODS on modern hardware and gaining the benefit of 18 years worth of optimizations made to the software *can* improve application performance. Whether *your* applications are i/o-bound in *your* environment and *will* benefit from the improved performance characteristics of ODS 51, however, is a question that only you can answer definitively.